# How to make a horizontal scrolling listView with dynamic height?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a listView with horizontal scrolling that I want to put a dynamic height of it, I don't want to set a height, for example height:100, because when I have an item that the text breaks the line I may have a problem.

By default the listview is taking up the entire height of the screen.

[image]

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: itensFilter.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ItemFilter(
              text: itensFilter[index],
              index: index,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide height on `Container`, also you are already providing height on `ItemFilter`

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        height: x,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: ListView.builder(
```

Or use `SingleChildScrollView` with Row.

```dart
 SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                //widget
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I don't want to fix a height, because I don't know what the maximum height is that one of these items can have.

Comment: What is your `ItemFilter`? Also can you include more about the parents?

Comment: The problem is not with him. The ItemFilter is a custom text widget only.

Comment: Ok try `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: @LayTexas very easy solution is just wrap your ItemFilter.

Comment: Wrap won't have scroll effect :) also as for your solution you are having list View with wrap for each item, like cost is n*wrap and having multichild widget just for single one

Comment: With SingleChildScrollView I have the same problem. In React I would solve this using the display: inline property.
In flutter I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you the parent and `ItemFilter` widget?